# fetch always 1st row of data from NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, azure-mobile-services

I am creating an iOS project using microsoft azure web services ad core data model. Also I am doing offline synching. In the response I will always get single row but while displaying output on screen in cellforRow AtIndexPath method, I am writting below line of code

```
 NSManagedObject *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

which states that in item I will have response reagrding current index path. But to fetch data from row all the time I am setting indexPath as 0 but after this line my code crashes and gives below response

```
*"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'"*
```

I also tried following ways

```
    NSManagedObject *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:<#(NSInteger)#> inSection:<#(NSInteger)#>] ];
    NSManagedObject *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:<#(NSInteger)#> inSection:<#(NSInteger)#>] ];
    NSManagedObject *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: 0 ];
```

but all in vain. Above error message is coming every time. (Server is responding properly and is returning data. I have already checked it).

The only code which sometimes gives correct data is

```
NSManagedObject *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:0] ];
```

but not every time. Can't tell in which scenario because this is happening randomly.

Please tell me how should I proceed to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It fails when there is nothing in the database so the fetch controller has no results when you ask it. Presumably you have statically set the number of rows to display or have a simple static view for the display so you're never actually checking the number of sections and rows that the fetch controller has.

For these lines:

```
NSManagedObject *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:<#(NSInteger)#> inSection:<#(NSInteger)#>] ];
```

You need to finish the parameters, but it would work assuming you ensure there is an item to get.

```
NSManagedObject *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:<#(NSInteger)#> inSection:<#(NSInteger)#>] ];
```

As above.

```
NSManagedObject *item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath: 0 ];
```

You can't pass a simple integer where an object is expected. You will have received a compile error telling you the same.

At minimum use `if ([self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects].count > 0)` yo check that you can request your single item.

Comment: That I am doing except the last check but table fetch is showing that it has fetched 1 row but when I am trying to fetch data at row = 0 then it is returning me nil..